# Could not connect when port forwarding?

Tags: 14.04, server, php, tcp-ip

I have a server that I'd like to be accessible from outside my home network. On my router, I am forwarding port 8978 from the server, and my server is running a php script and listening to port 8978.

However, when I try to test the connection (via something like PacketSender), I am getting this error:

```
Error: Could Not Connect
```

UFW is disabled, so I don't know why my port is not being exposed. I can SSH into the server remotely just fine (after forwarding the tcp port).

Is there something I am missing to make the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that I need to configure the iptables to get port forwarding to work using the command:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8978 -j ACCEPT
```